# How to prompt for index of Object Array and Display the Value?

Tags: java

I want to prompt a user through command line using a Scanner, to select from a predefined index of a Rational Array. After that I want to display the value of a selected Rational Object. How can I go about doing so ? Below is the code I have so far

```
//Array of rational objects that I want to let user select from

Rational[] rationals = {new Rationa(2, 3), new Rational(2, 18), new Rational(3,12)};

//Method for displaying value of object

public static void displayValue()
{
   System.out.println("Please select from index:  ");
}
```

Comment: @CenturiDamos My solution used command line by default. If you'd like to use a pop-up window, I would suggest looking into "JOptionPane"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a `.toString()` method for the `Rational` class. Then you may print the array like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rationals));
```

Then you may get input like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int index = sc.nextInt();
```

Ensure an acceptable number was given:

```
if(index > -1 && index < rationals.length){
  System.out.println(rationals[index]);
}else{
  System.out.println("Please input an acceptable value.")
}
```

If you want to keep asking for an input, until an acceptable one is given, you it can be done by using a `while` loop:

```
boolean askAgain = true;
while(askAgain){
  int index = sc.nextInt();
  if(index > -1 && index < rationals.length){
      System.out.println(rationals[index]);
      askAgain = false;
  }else{
      System.out.println("Please input an acceptable value.")
  }
}
```

EDIT: You may want to specify that the list starts at index `0`, not `1`.

EDIT2: `.toString()` example,

```
public class Person(){
  private String name;
  private int id;

  public Person(String n, int id){
    this.name = n;
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Name: " + name + ", " + id;
  }
}
```

The `toString();` method for an object class is just meant for returning the "useful information" as a `String`. In this example, for a `Person` class, the `toString()` method just returns the `name` and `id` of the user. So, for your `Rational` class, you can adjust that method to properly turn the object into a String.

Usage:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Jake", 1);
System.out.println(p1.toString());
```

OUTPUT:

```
"Name: Jake, 1"
```

Comment: Ok thank you. And when I create that .toString() method what should it return? I had it as public String toString() with empty statement brackets.

Comment: @CenturiDamos I added an edit to my answer to give an example for a toString() method.

Comment: @CenturiDamos No problem, if this answers your question fully you can select it as the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a `Scanner` to read input from the console. To use `Scanner`, you need to `import java.util.Scanner;`

This line creates the new `Scanner` and attaches it to `System.in`, which is the standard input for the program.
`Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);`

Now we can read an integer from input to select the index.

`int index = console.nextInt();`

After that, all you'll need to do is print out the value at `index` in your array.

Comment: If someone inputs "-1" or a number greater than rationals.length, the code will not work.

Comment: True, but I didn't want to bog down my answer with index protection and catching InputMismatchExceptions.